# C++ windows dll and libxml2 dependency woes

Tags: c++, windows, dependencies, libxml2

I develop a plug in dll, i.e. some other process loads my dll, C++ using VS...
I need to add xml parsing to my code and I use libxml2.

I have added that do my dll and now when the application tries to load my dll it fails to load. It is a dependency issue but I can not figure out what all other libs/dlls I need to add to my project.

Any ideas?

Comment: try [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

Comment: I have, when I drag my dll into the depends.exe, it does not show any red and it does NOT show libxml2.dll at all which is odd

Comment: you do load the libxml2.dll explicitly or implicitly via stub-lib? if you load it explicitely analyze libxml2.dll. another possibility is that one of your statics fail to construct.

Comment: explicit, the problem is with mscvr90.dll I do not want to go down that path :(